# Align PasswordBox text to center Windows store apps

Tags: alignment, windows-store-apps, text-alignment, passwordbox

I need to align password to center in PasswordBox like TextAlignment property do for TextBox, but unfortunately there is no TextAlignment property defined with PasswordBox element, In windows phone 8 i achieved this by modifying PasswordBox Template as this post -[PasswordBox textalignment in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402984/cannot-centre-align-password-in-passwordbox-in-wp7), 
But when searched for Windows Store App I found many post to regarding silverlight and wpf like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828417/centering-text-vertically-and-horizontally-in-textblock-and-passwordbox-in-windo?rq=1) but not working for Windows store apps.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Include namespace:

```
<!-- XML Namespace mapping. -->
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
```

Add the non-default control `HorizontalContentAlignment` to the style template.

```
<control HorizontalContentAlignment="horizontalAlignmentValue"/>
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334412%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)